# XmlAdapter Not Being Used in CXF

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I have an external (i.e. unmodifiable) `com.external.Money` class that has a `java.util.Currency` field with getters and setters. In my CXF jaxws web service, I have a request object like the one below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public ExampleRequest {
    private Money money;
    public Money getMoney() { return money; }
    public void setMoney(Money money) { this.money = money; }
}
```

When I try to start the service, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Currency does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.Currency
        at public java.util.Currency com.external.Money.getCurrency()
        at com.external.Money
        at public com.external.Money com.internal.ExampleRequest.getMoney()
        at com.internal.ExampleRequest
```

So, I created a `MoneyAdapter`, which converts the `Money` into something usable by JAXB, namely a `TransportableMoney` class with currency stored as a `String`. Ideally, I would create a `CurrencyAdapter` but since the currency field is encapsulated by an external class, I can't hook that up (or I don't know how to).

I am trying to hook up the adapter with a `package-info.java`:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MoneyAdapter.class, type=Money.class)
})
package com.internal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import com.external.Money;
```

The problem is, this doesn't work. Instead of the error above, I now get:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Currency does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.Currency
        at public java.util.Currency com.external.Money.getCurrency()
        at com.external.Money
```

**I think this is happening because `com.external.Money` has a no-arg constructor. When it does not have a no-arg constructor, this setup seems to work.**

Am I missing something here? Does anyone know how to force CXF to use the `XmlAdapter`?

**EDIT**

As Blaise Doughan pointed out, the configuration above DOES work using just the JAXB marshaller. It just doesn't work with CXF 2.6.0. Here's my main method:

```
SomeService ss = new SomeService();
JaxWsServerFactoryBean jwsfb = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
jwsfb.setServiceClass(SomeService.class);
jwsfb.setServiceBean(ss);
jwsfb.setAddress("http://localhost:9020/hello");
jwsfb.create();
```

maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

SomeService:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class SomeService {
    public ExampleRequest getRequest() {
        ExampleRequest request = new ExampleRequest();
        request.setMoney(new Money(Currency.getInstance("USD"), BigDecimal.ONE));
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(ExampleRequest req) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Created a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4537) and looks like it has already been resolved by CXF team (wow)!

Comment: Is `ExampleRequest` in the same `com.internal` package?  Also make sure you declare your adapter with `extends XmlAdapter<String, Money>`.  Also make sure your `package-info` class is being compiled?

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for your response. Yes - ExampleRequest is in com.internal and the adapter does extend XmlAdapter<String, Money>. I'm pretty sure package-info is being compiled since it has an impact on the execution (giving a different error message), but I'll double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me outside a CXF environment.  You can compare this to what you are doing.  If what you are doing matches then you are probably encountering a CXF issue.

**Money**

Below is a an implementation of the `Money` class based on the description from your question.

> I have an external (i.e. unmodifiable) com.external.Money class that
>   has a java.util.Currency field with getters and setters.

```
package com.external;

import java.util.Currency;

public class Money {

    private Currency currency;

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

}
```

**MoneyAdapter**

Below is an implementation of `MoneyAdapter` based on the description in your question:

> So, I created a MoneyAdapter, which converts the Money into something
>   usable by JAXB, namely a TransportableMoney class with currency stored
>   as a String

```
package com.internal;

import java.util.Currency;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import com.external.Money;

public class MoneyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<TransportableMoney, Money> {

    @Override
    public Money unmarshal(TransportableMoney v) throws Exception {
        Money money = new Money();
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(v.currency);
        money.setCurrency(currency);
        return money;
    }

    @Override
    public TransportableMoney marshal(Money v) throws Exception {
        TransportableMoney transportableMoney = new TransportableMoney();
        transportableMoney.currency = v.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
        return transportableMoney;
    }

}
```

**TransportableMoney**

```
package com.internal;

public class TransportableMoney {

    public String currency;

}
```

**package-info**

This is your `package-info` class taken directly from your question.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MoneyAdapter.class, type=Money.class)
})
package com.internal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import com.external.Money;
```

**ExampleRequest**

This is your `ExampleRequest` class taken directly from your question.

```
package com.internal;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.external.Money;

@XmlRootElement
public class ExampleRequest {
    private Money money;
    public Money getMoney() { return money; }
    public void setMoney(Money money) { this.money = money; }
}
```

**Demo**

Below is some sample code that reads in XML to objects and writes it back out to prove that everything works.

```
package com.internal;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExampleRequest.class);

        File xml = new File("src/com/internal/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ExampleRequest er = (ExampleRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(er, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Here is the example input and output XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<exampleRequest>
    <money>
        <currency>USD</currency>
    </money>
</exampleRequest>
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming this as a CXF issue. If you know why it might be happening in CXF, please let me know. Otherwise I'll raise this on a CXF issue tracker.

Comment: @andy - Could be related to the package level annotation.  If you move the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to the `money` property on `ExampleRequest` does everything work?

Comment: Yeah, it works then. However, in my actual project, I have too many references to the object to count, as a parameter and return value. If possible, I'd like to have a package-level annotation handle it. I've just opened the following issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4537